# MySQL: Treating a whole expression as a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

Is there any way to treat a whole part of a regular expression as a string?

Example:

```
WHERE `head` REGEXP '" . implode("|", $selectedHEADs) . "'
```

where `$selectedHEADs` can be filled with $, |, /, \ and all kinds of special-characters. I want to match those as normal letters. Is there any PHP-function or any "tweaks" in MySQL to make this available?

Just so you know, I only want each of the items to be treated as strings, the | between them in the "implode" should still be treated as a separator between different patterns.

Comment: Sorry for the bland, generic advice, but it struck me: Instead of using a `REGEXP`, have you considered `"WHERE head IN ('" . implode("','", array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $selectedHeads)) . "')"` or something comparable? As a rule of thumb, I feel regular expressions are best left as a last resort, though your mileage may vary.

Comment: Also, something I don't quite want to post as an answer because it's an external reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html - check out lvaro's comment. Which is to say, the direct answer to your question is 'lots of backslashes', but it gets a bit ugly very quickly.